# Can't start any application - unable to open connection to X

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I have a strange problem on one pc that seems to have developed over the last couple of days. I log in and my wireless connection will fail continuously. While this is happening, I can open applications. If I open a terminal and restart network manager with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

the wireless connection will be fixed, but no applications will subsequently launch. Attempting to launch them through the already-open terminal will show errors about being unable to open a connection to X.

- Kubuntu 15.04 64 bit
- using nvidia-346-updates
- lspci shows network controller as Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev01)
- I usually use KDE, but this is happening in XFCE also

[Output when trying to launch applications](https://gist.github.com/thelionroars/299bbe22fe039e031c4f)

[Xorg.0.log and Xorg.1.log](https://gist.github.com/thelionroars/bd502e06a77b230a43a3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a problem with the .Xauthority file in the home directory. It should be recreated if you delete it, upon restarting the X server. I entered

```
rm $HOME/.Xauthority*
```

and rebooted, and can now launch applications.